# How to make pyramid of a string?

Tags: python, nested-loops

I want to make a pyramid of a string for an exercise.
I just don't know how to do it.
For example:

```
string = "these***are***just***random***words*"
```

and the pyramid I want to make is:

```
         t
        hes
       e***a
      re***ju
     st***rand
    om***words*
```

How do I do this?

```
def draw_pyramid(string, size):
    if size > 15:
        size = 15
    if size < 5:
        size = 5
    l = string * size
    for i in range(size + 1):
        stars = i
        p = l[0:stars]
        spaces = size - i
        print(" " * spaces + p)


def main():
    size = int(input("How many layers do you want it to be?: "))
    string = "these***are***just***random***words*"
    draw_pyramid(string, size)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Result:

```
         t
        th
       the
      thes
     these
    these*
   these**
  these***
 these***a
these***ar
```

Comment: Take a look at your line `p = l[0:stars]` and consider whether your slice of `l` should always start at `0` or whether it should maybe be something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string.center()` to get the strings nicely aligned in the center. To get the right characters from `l` I use a `start` and an `end` variable:

```
def draw_pyramid(string, size):
    if size > 15:
        size = 15
    if size < 5:
        size = 5
    length = size * 2 - 1
    l = string * size
    start = 0
    end = 0
    for stars in range(1, size + 1):
        end += stars * 2 - 1
        p = l[start:end]
        start = end
        print(p.center(length))
```

Output :

```
How many layers do you want it to be?: 10
         t         
        hes        
       e***a       
      re***ju      
     st***rand     
    om***words*    
   these***are**   
  *just***random*  
 **words*these***a 
re***just***random*
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are indexing `l` is wrong, based on what you want to achieve. If you study your desired output, you see that on the first row you want the substring `l[0:1]`, on the second row `l[1:4]`, then `l[4:9]`, `l[9:16]` etc. The starting index is the sum of the first `i` odd elements, i.e. 1+3+5+.. and the stopping index is the sum of the first `i+1` odd elements. Thus, at each step, you want `l[i**2:(i+1)**2]`, with `i` starting at 0.

So your function should look like this

```python
def draw_pyramid(string, size):
    if size > 15:
        size = 15
    if size < 5:
        size = 5
    l = string * size
    for i in range(size + 1):
        p = l[i**2:(i+1)**2]
        spaces = size - i
        print(" " * spaces + p)
```

and it produces the desired output